# Put a custom js code in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I try to put a code like this : http://codepen.io/lormski/pen/meXadK/

```
$(function() {
   $("#tabs").tabs({
   show: {
   effect: "blind",
   direction: "right",
   duration: 300
  }
});
   $("#accordion").accordion();

   var btn = $('#accordion li a');
   var wrapper = $('#accordion li');

    $(btn).on('click', function() {
    $(btn).removeClass('active');
    $(btn).parent().find('.addon').removeClass('fadein');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).parent().find('.addon').addClass('fadein');
  });
});
```

In my wordpress website (theme Avada)

If someone know how to do this ;)

Comment: do you need to know how to link custom js file to your theme ?

Comment: Yes please ! Thank You

Answer (score 0):

`$` selector in WordPress will fail, you need to start your code as :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  //your code here using $
});
</script>
```

In AVADA you can go to Options -> Advanced -> Code Fields (Tracking etc.) and add the code there.

EDIT:

Notice that codepen has included jQuery UI!

You also need to include jQuery ui in your theme if it isn't included already. Add this to AVADAs child's functions.php

```
function my_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
```

Hope that helps

Comment: i have this error in the console :

(index):218 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).tabs is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):218i @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.3:2j.fireWith @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.3:2n.extend.ready @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.3:2K @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.3:2

Comment: I updated to include jquery ui. Let me know if that works.